# Architectural Differences in Java MVC Web Frameworks

Tags: java, model-view-controller, web-applications

I'm trying to choose an AJAX-friendly Java framework for my first web application and am interested in first
understanding the architectural differences between the different flavors that are out there.

I like the concept of MVC frameworks, and so am primarily considering the following:

- Any JSF variety (ICEFaces, RichFaces, PrimeFaces, etc.)
- Spring Web Flow
- ZK
- Wicket

I've downloaded each of these projects and tried to follow their samples/tutorials, and there is
so much information to ingest I figured I'd take a breather and come here to cover some preliminaries
first.

**I'm interested in how each of these frameworks implements the MVC pattern**. Obviously, something rooted
in JSF (like ICEFaces) is going to have a different architecture than Spring. I'm sure that this is a
**huge** question, so I'm not looking for a full-blown tutorial on each of these frameworks; I'm just
curious as to what sort of artifacts (Java sources, XML config files, etc.) a developer has to write in
order to build a single AJAX-driven page using these. *I'm interested in the differences to their approach*,
nothing more.

For instance, I would imagine that each framework at some point uses a `FrontController` (or its likes) to
map `HttpRequests` to the right `Controller` implementation. That `Controller` (bean) would then need to do
some processing, possibly hit the database for some information (using ormapping and forming the `Model`), and
then construct a `View`/`HttpResponse` to send back to the client. This is an oversimplification I'm sure, but
there has to be an easy way to explain the high-level architecture for how each of these frameworks accomplishes
that.

Comment: What IDE are you gonna use? Framework support varies wildly between them and a good plugin can make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Good point Viruzzo - it would be Eclipse. Again this question is more about the theoretical differences between how these frameworks implement MVC than it is a mechanism to help me decide which to choose. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: i wish i could answer this, but i have only used jsf and spring.. i will say, stay away from jsf. it is too heavy handed about the request/response cycle.

Comment: Thanks mkoryak - do you mind if I ask what you mean by "heavy-handed"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Struts uses the ActionServlet (with Struts2 now its just Action) as the controller and model and jsp is the view.

For Spring MVC is achieved by DispatcherServlet which does the routing and Model is not bound to any framework related object you can use any.

JSF - UI jsp or jsf itself, Model - ManagedBean, Controller - FacesServlet.

I did some similar search for my own project a while ago, have a look at the links below:

Comparison based on multiple parameters : http://static.raibledesigns.com/repository/presentations/ComparingJavaWebFrameworks.pdf

Difference between JSF and Struts

http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/what-are-the-fundamental-differences-between-struts-and-jsf.html

Somewhat related post

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633583/which-mvc-is-better-spring-or-struts

Spring and JSF

http://blog.springsource.org/2007/04/21/what-spring-web-flow-offers-jsf-developers/

Spring MVC : http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html

Best Fit For JSF Component Library: [Primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org) based on my own experience

From IBM Clearing the FUD : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jsf1/

Hope this gives you some insight.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at **Matt Raible's talk on Comparing JVM Web Frameworks [here](http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/my_comparing_jvm_web_frameworks)**. You can also consider looking at `Spring MVC` and '[Tapestry](http://tapestry.apache.org/)`.

Also, this [link](https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=0AtkkDCT2WDMXdC1HOEtnUHpCejJMbUhGeGJWUmh5dVE&hl=en&output=html) gives you a **matrix on capabilities of various java web frameworks.**

Answer (score 0):

You should also check out the Play framework. I have used it a little and really like it.

It is very easy to get started with minimal configuration (reminds me of Rails).

http://www.playframework.org/